# Edit the "Post updated. View post" link

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, post-editor

Is it possible to edit the "Post updated. View post" link and remove the "View post" entirely? Also change the "Post" to the name of a cpt?

Thanks guys!

Update:

Here is the code I used and it worked like a charm. I hope this helps others!

In my example I use "Contact" as my cpt:

[image]

```
add_filter('post_updated_messages', 'contact_updated_messages');
function contact_updated_messages( $messages ) {

$messages['contact'] = array(
0 => '', // Unused. Messages start at index 1.
1 => sprintf( __('Contact updated. <a href="%s">View Contact</a>'), esc_url( get_permalink($post_ID) ) ),
2 => __('Custom field updated.'),
3 => __('Custom field deleted.'),
4 => __('Contact updated.'),
/* translators: %s: date and time of the revision */
5 => isset($_GET['revision']) ? sprintf( __('Contact restored to revision from %s'), wp_post_revision_title( (int) $_GET['revision'], false ) ) : false,
6 => sprintf( __('Contact published. <a href="%s">View Contact</a>'), esc_url( get_permalink($post_ID) ) ),
7 => __('Contact saved.'),
8 => sprintf( __('Contact submitted. <a target="_blank" href="%s">Preview Contact</a>'), esc_url( add_query_arg( 'preview', 'true', get_permalink($post_ID) ) ) ),
9 => sprintf( __('Contact scheduled for: <strong>%1$s</strong>. <a target="_blank" href="%2$s">Preview Contact</a>'),
  // translators: Publish box date format, see http://php.net/date
  date_i18n( __( 'M j, Y @ G:i' ), strtotime( $post->post_date ) ), esc_url( get_permalink($post_ID) ) ),
10 => sprintf( __('Contact draft updated. <a target="_blank" href="%s">Preview Contact</a>'), esc_url( add_query_arg( 'preview', 'true', get_permalink($post_ID) ) ) ),
);

return $messages;
}
```

Comment: Make it open in a new tab by following my directions here: http://codebucket.io/code/danielhickman/make-post-published-view-post-open-in-a-new-tab/

Answer (score 4):

You can filter the update messages: `add_filter('post_updated_messages', 'your_message_function');`

look in /wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php to see the where the default messages are set.

Comment: Thanks Milo! Using your advice I have found what I wanted to do. I will edit my original post with the answer.

Comment: Thanks here too! Made them all open in a new tab by adding 'target="_blank"' to each <a> in the messages. Saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 3):

To make this work for all CPTs, I found a gist that abstracts it into a simple function to drop in functions.php

https://gist.github.com/benklocek/2b510994c3ecbe508af6

```
/**
* Replaces "Post" in the update messages for custom post types on the "Edit"post screen.
* For example, for a "Product" custom post type, "Post updated. View Post." becomes "Product updated. View Product".
*
* @param array $messages The default WordPress messages.
*/

function pico_custom_update_messages( $messages ) {
global $post, $post_ID;

$post_types = get_post_types( array( 'show_ui' => true, '_builtin' => false ), 'objects' );

foreach( $post_types as $post_type => $post_object ) {

    $messages[$post_type] = array(
        0  => '', // Unused. Messages start at index 1.
        1  => sprintf( __( '%s updated. <a href="%s">View %s</a>' ), $post_object->labels->singular_name, esc_url( get_permalink( $post_ID ) ), $post_object->labels->singular_name ),
        2  => __( 'Custom field updated.' ),
        3  => __( 'Custom field deleted.' ),
        4  => sprintf( __( '%s updated.' ), $post_object->labels->singular_name ),
        5  => isset( $_GET['revision']) ? sprintf( __( '%s restored to revision from %s' ), $post_object->labels->singular_name, wp_post_revision_title( (int) $_GET['revision'], false ) ) : false,
        6  => sprintf( __( '%s published. <a href="%s">View %s</a>' ), $post_object->labels->singular_name, esc_url( get_permalink( $post_ID ) ), $post_object->labels->singular_name ),
        7  => sprintf( __( '%s saved.' ), $post_object->labels->singular_name ),
        8  => sprintf( __( '%s submitted. <a target="_blank" href="%s">Preview %s</a>'), $post_object->labels->singular_name, esc_url( add_query_arg( 'preview', 'true', get_permalink( $post_ID ) ) ), $post_object->labels->singular_name ),
        9  => sprintf( __( '%s scheduled for: <strong>%1$s</strong>. <a target="_blank" href="%2$s">Preview %s</a>'), $post_object->labels->singular_name, date_i18n( __( 'M j, Y @ G:i' ), strtotime( $post->post_date ) ), esc_url( get_permalink( $post_ID ) ), $post_object->labels->singular_name ),
        10 => sprintf( __( '%s draft updated. <a target="_blank" href="%s">Preview %s</a>'), $post_object->labels->singular_name, esc_url( add_query_arg( 'preview', 'true', get_permalink( $post_ID ) ) ), $post_object->labels->singular_name ),
        );
}

return $messages;
}
add_filter( 'post_updated_messages', 'pico_custom_update_messages' );
```

*Note: The function names in the `add_filter` method and the actual function definition differ from each other in the gist. This has been rectified in the pasted snippet above.*

Comment: Please add the relevant code into your answer, thanks.

Comment: That's amazing! Is it possible for it to use the native translated strings? Then it would be perfect!